# Angular 2 - 404 on http.get local HTML file

Tags: angular

I am getting a 404 when trying to fetch a local HTML file via http.get. Can't figure out the problem. Code / Screen crops:

*Component:*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

//
// Resembles the view for creating and editing card visuals and metadata.
//

@Component({
    selector: 'cards',
    templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cards.component.css']
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(public http: Http) { }
    defaultCards: any = [
        {
            name: 'Default',
            frontUrl: './templates/default/front.html',
            backUrl: './templates/default/back.html'
        }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('./templates/default/front.html').subscribe(
            (res) => console.log(res.json()),
            (error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knhch.jpg)

Console logs 404. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are requesting a file that does not exist. You request a file relatively to the typescript file but the request is made relatively to the current URL.

Comment: Check your html file location